# How would you create a module which doesn't need to be required, such as standard methods like chr, ord, inject?

Tags: ruby

When you start a new Ruby project, you have all the standard functions by default. If you want gems and additional ruby files, you need to require them.

I would like create a function that gets loaded by default with the rest of the standard functions.

Comment: **Why**? If it's not a "standard" function, you *should* have to require it.

Comment: I understand that this is the default way. I guess I am more curious about how all of the standard-library functions can be called on by default. I thought it may have been possible to do somehow, but it looks impossible to do without requiring it somewhere. It's just that at this moment how the standard-library functions are included by default seems like black magic to me.

Comment: It's not magic, they're just built-in.

Comment: @Singularity: see my comment below regarding standard library.

Comment: Yes, I seen it. That makes things more logical now. Thanks for the comment, it helped out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you want these functions to be available. Ruby has a feature sometimes referred to as "open classes" or "monkey patching" that allows you to add functionality to existing classes. You can simply declare a class with the same name as one that already exists in the Ruby standard library and define methods within it like so:

```
class Array
  def double_values
    map { |v| v * 2 }
  end
end
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
[1,2,3].double_values # => [2,4,6]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be restricted to the said file though?
As an example of what I would like to do is:
a_to_i.rb
  `class Array
    def a_to_i
      self.map(&:to_i)
    end
  end`
test.rb
  array = ['1', '2', '3']
  p array.a_to_i

I would like to achieve this without requiring the file a_to_i.rb or adding the code to the file test.rb as well

Comment: If you want it available to other classes, just define it higher on the chain. For example, if you wanted it available to all enumerables, you'd define it on Enumerable. Above that you have Object, Kernel and BasicObject. `Array.ancestors` will show you the hierarchy.

Comment: If you don't require the file, how would Ruby know you wanted to use it?

Comment: I'm unsure, that's when I ask the higher question of how are the standard-library functions called by default? Is it built into the interpreter, or is it all required at some point somewhere transparently?

Comment: @Singularity: you're mixing "core ruby" and "standard library". Core ruby functionality you don't have to require. It's just there (`Array` class, for example). Although stdlib is also shipped with ruby, you have to `require` its parts you want to use. OpenStruct, for example.

Answer (score 0):

just reopen the class you want to add methods to

```
class String

  def some_method
    "hi there!"
  end

end
```

Comment: He will have to require a file with this definition, though. Otherwise it won't be visible.